# How to use netty in mysql jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc, netty

Hello all I am newbie in networking. I am sorry if asking this to noob question for you.

I am creating an application which need a server to reply a ResultSet object query. What I mean is, my client applications needs to request some String query to the server.

Example
SELECT * FROM my_table
Then when the server reply it should be in ResultSet object. So that on the client it should be only populating that ResultSet object. Is this even possible? If so, can you give me an example on how to do it?

Comment: you want send a ResultSet object from server to client??

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted. I have a new question here.. I have another question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465408/sending-and-receiving-arraylist-objects-or-array-objects-in-netty/30477312#30477312

Comment: Send a resultset I think is not possible.

Comment: Ahh OK I have a new question can you help? Its not sending the resultset anymore but sending object from result search query.