# Sending and receiving ArrayList Objects or Array Objects in Netty

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, netty

Hello all I am really new to netty. What I want is something like this. On my client I want to enter a String query example `SELECT * FROM drivers`. I am using an mysql xampp server. Then my server will query it down and add it to arraylist

```
 private List<Drivers> getRecords(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

        List<Drivers> records = new ArrayList<Drivers>();
        while(rs.next()){
            records.add(new Drivers(rs.getInt("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name")));
        }
        return records;
    }
```

After that it will send ArrayList objects back to the client.

My problem now is on how to populate it to the client

Here is my server pipeline

```
public class ServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final SslContext sslCtx;

    public ServerInitializer(SslContext sslCtx) {
        this.sslCtx = sslCtx;
    }

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        // Add SSL handler first to encrypt and decrypt everything.
        // In this example, we use a bogus certificate in the server side
        // and accept any invalid certificates in the client side.
        // You will need something more complicated to identify both
        // and server in the real world.
        pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));

        // On top of the SSL handler, add the text line codec.
        /*
        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder());
          */
        //pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        /*

        */
        //pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder",new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1048576, 0, 4, 0, 4));
        //pipeline.addLast("bytesDecoder",new ByteArrayDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));

        // and then business logic.
        pipeline.addLast(new ServerHandler());
    }
}
```

My Client Pipeline

```
 public class ClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

        private final SslContext sslCtx;

        public ClientInitializer(SslContext sslCtx) {
            this.sslCtx = sslCtx;
        }

        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

            // Add SSL handler first to encrypt and decrypt everything.
            // In this example, we use a bogus certificate in the server side
            // and accept any invalid certificates in the client side.
            // You will need something more complicated to identify both
            // and server in the real world.
            pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), Client.HOST, Client.PORT));

            // On top of the SSL handler, add the text line codec.

            /*
            pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
            pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder());
              */
            //pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
            /*
            */
            pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder",new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1048576, 0, 4, 0, 4));
            pipeline.addLast("bytesDecoder",new ByteArrayDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
            // and then business logic.
            pipeline.addLast(new ClientHandler());
        }
    }
```

My Server Channel Handler

```
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

    @Override
    public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        // Once session is secured, send a greeting and register the channel to the global channel
        // list so the channel received the messages from others.
        ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).handshakeFuture().addListener(
                new GenericFutureListener<Future<Channel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> future) throws Exception {

                        channels.add(ctx.channel());
                    }
        });
    }

    private List<Drivers> getRecords(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

        List<Drivers> records=new ArrayList<Drivers>();
        while(rs.next()){
            records.add(new Drivers(rs.getInt(0), rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), 
                    rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getInt(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10), 
                    rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14), 
                    rs.getString(15), rs.getString(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), rs.getString(19)));
        }
        return records;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
    {
         // Send the received message to all channels but the current one.
        for (Channel c: channels) {
            if (c != ctx.channel()) {
                c.writeAndFlush("[" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + "] " + msg + '\n');

            } else {

                try {
                    new DataManipulator();
                    System.out.print(msg.toString());
                    ResultSet rs = DataManipulator.generalQuery(msg.toString());
                    c.writeAndFlush(getRecords(rs));

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                        | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // Close the connection if the client has sent 'bye'.
        if ("bye".equals(msg.toString().toLowerCase())) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

My Client Channel Handler

```
public class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object[]> {

     static int count = 1;
     @Override
     public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
         System.out.println(ctx.read());
     }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object[] msg)
            throws Exception {
        // Still don't know how to receive the data.

    }
}
```

Please help how to perfectly done this on netty.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ByteArrayDecoder` and `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` in your pipeline. What you need are `ObjectDecoder` and `ObjectEncoder`, and that should be all (except for your last handler.)

Comment: Its a pleasure to be answered by the creator of netty. I will try it out. My problem now is on how to populate Array on my client. I mean how to extract the array on the client. I tried to use the following

Comment: ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object[]> {
 @Override
 protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object[] msg)
   throws Exception {
  /// Extract the Object[] msg here, but how?
  /// I tried to output. 
  System.out.println(msg); // No output
 }
}

Comment: ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
 @Override
 protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
   throws Exception {
  /// Extract the Object msg here, but how?
  /// I tried to output. 
  System.out.println(msg); // No output
  
 }
}

Comment: Any idea? how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I happened to solved this problem with a little trick.
In your case, I think the following sample code might help.

By defined A **NettyMessage** Class

```
public class NettyMessage implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private  String action;
    private  List<Drivers> body;
    // getter and setter....
```

And within **ServerHandler**,

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    List<Drivers> list = c.writeAndFlush(getRecords(rs));
    ctx.writeAndFlush(new NettyMessage("myaction", list));
}
```

within **ClientHandler**,

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    NettyMessage message = (NettyMessage)msg;
    List<Drivers> driverList = message.getBody();
}
```

but don't extends **SimpleChannelInboundHandler**

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it out. But why do I need that action parameter in the constructor?

Comment: "but don't extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler" do you mean I will just use ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter?

Comment: @Yves Gonzaga if you extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler you will not override channelRead method. extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter as you might have try. Action parameter is no necessary, but somehow I have use it on my work to filter incoming message, I just left it here in case you will need it too.

Comment: I tried to use your approach. However, when I try to iterate to the arraylist it wont output anything. Is there something I miss on Pipeline decoding and encoding? NettyMessage message = (NettyMessage)msg;
  ArrayList<Drivers> driverList = (ArrayList<Drivers>) message.getBody();
  Iterator<Drivers> itr = driverList.iterator();
  for(Drivers drivers : driverList){
   
   System.out.println(drivers.getFirstName());
  }

Comment: I use these two,

ch.pipeline().addLast(new ObjectDecoder(1024, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(this.getClass().getClassLoader())));
ch.pipeline().addLast(new ObjectEncoder());

Comment: make sure NettyMessage implements Serializable interface

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79204/discussion-between-yves-gonzaga-and-honwhy).